# downloading images using curl library in a loop over data frame

Tags: r, for-loop, curl, tidyverse

I'm trying download images for a bird species that I study from a Google Form (actually the responses sheet from that form). In this abbreviated data set, I have each bird's ID, date it was captured, and multiple images of the bird from different angles (tail, frontPop, etc.).

I'd like to loop through this data set, download each type of image, and name it by the bird's ID, capture date, and image type (which corresponds to the column name):

**189307140_2019-01-14_tail.jpg**

I can use the 'curl' package to download an image from each Google Drive link in the spreadsheet like this:

```
library(curl)
curl_download(url = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1kra8bSf4WMpoK8BTyFip2OxmUuz30Thl', 
              destfile = 'bird.jpg')
```

But I'm stuck on a more elegant way of doing this in a loop (over each bird and photo type in my dataset)...

Here's an example of the data:

```
dat <- structure(list(markerID = c(189307136L, 189307145L, 183337360L
), date = structure(c(17907, 17910, 17910), class = "Date"), 
    tail = c("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=13S9s_j6acfndEz4HbpG-v2ZRyT8LLgji", 
    "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=19XpBTLws94wtCtgPF6oXKM_GZ_cV4oMf", 
    "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1I5zA8tJdEv26EzI9rwBSN5tVsASyT4Cl"
    ), frontPop = c("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1lJgl3hin9sWQcV40aJgdYPQM6jzch2Lb", 
    "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1QdB1KmyHrlKkTlux0fkyI1Aw-Pe15sYF", 
    "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1xqNT9CPVfMj2ksxqMONGbWXyJKaKtLuR"
    ), backPop = c("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1YAe4S7_LIrLsbOW2qCBuWjyOr_SgT54T", 
    "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1QOC8rPDjWfy6PVSaXFycf4jDyUnV-Vbv", 
    "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1Gyo4lXgp0nXbsdd0jA_kk1m2jW8RGGIY"
    )), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

    # A tibble: 3 x 5
   markerID date       tail                                         frontPop                                     backPop                                     
      <int> <date>     <chr>                                        <chr>                                        <chr>                                       
1 189307136 2019-01-11 https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download… https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download… https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download…
2 189307145 2019-01-14 https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download… https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download… https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download…
3 183337360 2019-01-14 https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download… https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download… https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download…
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an elegant way to solve your problem using `library(purrr)`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(curl)

dat <- structure(
  list(markerID = c(189307136L, 189307145L, 183337360L), 
       date = structure(c(17907, 17910, 17910), class = "Date"), 
       tail = c("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=13S9s_j6acfndEz4HbpG-v2ZRyT8LLgji", 
                "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=19XpBTLws94wtCtgPF6oXKM_GZ_cV4oMf", 
                "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1I5zA8tJdEv26EzI9rwBSN5tVsASyT4Cl"), 
       frontPop = c("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1lJgl3hin9sWQcV40aJgdYPQM6jzch2Lb", 
                    "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1QdB1KmyHrlKkTlux0fkyI1Aw-Pe15sYF", 
                    "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1xqNT9CPVfMj2ksxqMONGbWXyJKaKtLuR"), 
       backPop = c("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1YAe4S7_LIrLsbOW2qCBuWjyOr_SgT54T", 
                   "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1QOC8rPDjWfy6PVSaXFycf4jDyUnV-Vbv", 
                   "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1Gyo4lXgp0nXbsdd0jA_kk1m2jW8RGGIY")), 
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
  row.names = c(NA, -3L))

read_and_title <- as_mapper(~curl_download(url = ..4, 
                                           destfile = paste0(..1,"_",..2,"_",..3,".png")))

dat %>% 
  gather(key = "photo_type", value = "url", 3:5) %>% 
  pmap_chr(read_and_title)
#> [1] "189307136_17907_tail.png"     "189307145_17910_tail.png"    
#> [3] "183337360_17910_tail.png"     "189307136_17907_frontPop.png"
#> [5] "189307145_17910_frontPop.png" "183337360_17910_frontPop.png"
#> [7] "189307136_17907_backPop.png"  "189307145_17910_backPop.png" 
#> [9] "183337360_17910_backPop.png"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>